# To set conditions for target attribute of commandlink tag in jsf through javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I want to set conditions through javascript for the target attribute of commandlink in jsf.

Only if the condition is true then only the target attribute will work otherwise not.

Or can we pass values for the target attribute of commandlink through javascript.

Here is my code :

```
<script language=javascript >
function open_win()
{

var selecttype = document.getElementById("frmList:Export").value;
var datetype1 = document.getElementById("frmList:fld_Date").value;

   if (selecttype == "PDF" && datetype1 != false)
return target = "_blank";
else 
return target = "_self"  
  }
 </script>


 <h:commandLink  target = "" onclick = "open_win()" style="border: none;"     
    actionListener="#{report.yes}">
    <h:graphicImage   
    style="border: none;" value="#{User.imageBasePath}/btn_yes.gif" />
  </h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSF renders commandLink as HTML `<a>` tag which can be modified in Javascript. Yes you can pass the target attribute in Javascript by doing,

```
document.getElementById("frmList:reportLink").target = "_blank";
```

and

```
 <h:commandLink id="reportLink" onclick = "open_win()" style="border: none;" 
                    actionListener="#{report.yes}">
```

Better approach would be to add this logic in your commandLink ,

```
<h:commandLink  target = "#{(export=='PDF' and fld_Date)?'_blank':'_self'}"
                style="border: none;" actionListener="#{report.yes}">
    <h:graphicImage style="border: none;" 
                value="#{User.imageBasePath}/btn_yes.gif" />
  </h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, Thanks for the above sugges, but its not working. The PDF is opening in the same window. Its not opening in the new tab/window.

Comment: @user2161498 you may need to tweak the condition in command link . See the generated HTML to see if your page is generated with _blank

Comment: I am new to JSF & software field. so brief me